# Can 2 different apps have access to one Firebase cloud?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, cloud

So I have recently made a driver and user app both of which need to exchange data. Is it possible for both to have the same database in Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for both to have the same database in Firebase?

Yes, without any problem. The two apps just have to share the same [Firebase config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android#configure-firebase).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, you can use the same google-services config file in both of the projects, and both of them can access/modify the same database.